# Use R code or Windows user variable ("%userprofile%") in YAML?

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, user-profile

In my yaml call I have

```
---
title: "`r paste0('Test. Done ', format(Sys.Date(), '%B-%Y'))`"
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 7
    reference_docx: %userprofile%\Documents\template.docx
---
```

But YAML complains about `%userprofile%`. Is it possible to include such a variable?

I have tried e.g.

```
reference_docx: "`r file.path(path.expand('~'), 'skabelon.docx')`"
```

But that still results in this YAML error.

```
pandoc.exe: `r file.path(path.expand('~'), 'skabelon.docx')`: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I guess this meens that the r expression is not processed before the yaml? I have checked that the file is there... Or is it becayse pandoc is using another 'userprofile' ? how can I check this?

I can however use such a call in the `Title` variable, as per the updated title above. I guess this must be a specific knitr issue.

Comment: You should give the YAML error you get for the second input.

Comment: I've updated the question @flyx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters in the `output` field is only understood by **rmarkdown**. Pandoc does not understand them, so you need to make sure **rmarkdown** can evaluate the expression. Since **rmarkdown** uses the **yaml** package to read the YAML metadata, and **yaml**'s syntax for R expressions is `!expr`, you can put the R expression after `!expr`, e.g.

```
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 7
    reference_docx: !expr file.path(Sys.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Documents', 'template.docx')
```

Comment: This works @Yihui. But does this mean that "!expr" supersedes "`r"? I can find this documented in the yaml package - but not elsewhere. Iin my example "'r" works for date fields but !expr does not. On the other hand !expr works for reference_docx but "'r" does not? Whats the difference?

Comment: Good question. The `r` syntax is only understood by knitr. In your case, you want rmarkdown to understand it is an R expression. Since rmarkdown uses yaml to parse the YAML metadata, and yaml can only understand `!expr`.

Comment: This trips me up every time. I can use "`r Sys.time()`" in the date field of YAML, but have to use `!expr path_to_doc.docx` for a reference template. knitr + RMd is great, but this is unintuitive and non-obvious, to me at least.

Comment: @MattCowgill I definitely agree with you.

Comment: In any case thank you for all your packages @Yihui, you’ve made a huge contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can include such a variable, but you should quote the scalar in which put it (either single quotes or double quotes). Within a quoted scalar the `%` doesn't have any special meaning only the single quote has (in single quoted strings, or the backslash (`\`) in double quoted strings.

Any further interpretation of that scalar as Windows variable is outside of the scope of YAML and needs to be done by your program.

The scalar:

```
"`r file.path(path.expand('~'), 'skabelon.docx')`"
```

is correct YAML and shout not throw an error (but of course is nothing else for YAML than a buch of characters starting and ending with a backquote, no interpretation should be done on that by the parser).

Comment: Okay  - thanks. For now I am assuming its a knitr issue

Comment: The YAML is completely parsed and then handed to the knitr, which expects a certain syntax it looks like it doesn't do anything with the backquotes. I would first hard-code the correct path in the YAML scalar without any backquotes and then gradually replace parts with things that knitr can evaluate, every time checking that it still works.

Comment: If I replace the title value with the value for reference_docx, and hardcode the output of the call in to the reference_docx value, the correct path is printed in the title (like this: https://i.imgur.com/5JkCVoN.png). So I guess it must be a knitr issue.